# Retrieving data from a database with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Why can't I get all data from database when it is looped already? I'm only getting the last row of data from database.

HTML:

```
<div id="registerlist">
</div>

        <script>
        $.getJSON("http://url/getapplicantdetails.php?callback=?",{},function(data)
            {
            var rlist = (data.fullname);
            var fullndear = document.getElementById('registerlist');
            fullndear.innerHTML = rlist;

            });
        </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-Type: application/json");

include_once ("dbcon.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblregistered";
    $select = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
 {
 echo $_GET['callback']."  (".json_encode(array("fullname"=>$row['fullname'],"email"=>$row['email'],"username"=>$row['username'],)).");";
 }
 ?>
```

Anyone please tell me what am I missing or what's wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying the data in the browser more records that's wrong display json multidimensional array and process it in the loop.

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-Type: application/json");

include_once ("dbcon.php");

//local array
$data = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblregistered";
    $select = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
 {

    //fill the local array
    $data[] = array("fullname"=>$row['fullname'],"email"=>$row['email'],"username"=>$row['username']);


 }

 //display the output
 echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: add console.log(data) and see the output in the firebug plugin

Comment: This is on the condsole:
[Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]

I get undefined on display

Comment: you are appending the call back by seeing your code there is no meaning try this in PHP code - echo json_encode($data);

Comment: it has no display nothing in console

Comment: put the print_r($data) after the foreach loop and see what you are getting. The database table is empty i guess. or PHP code not returning anything from the database